# How to get split function to work properly?

Tags: javascript, split

i am trying to create a function that takes a form input (in this case the name), splits it using the space, and then sends either an error message or an all good message. however, it fails to acknowledge conditions for some reason? it always says that its correct even if i only input a name.

```
function validateName(){
    var nameVal = document.getElementById("yourname");
    var nameParts = nameVal.toString().split(" ");
    if (nameParts.length<2) {
        document.getElementById("yourname").nextSibling.innerHTML = "Please enter your First and Last Name.";} 
    else {
        document.getElementById("yourname").nextSibling.innerHTML = "Thank you for entering your First and Last Name!";
    }
}
```

ive tried changing the code in various ways but there is always some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add `.value` in the first line of your function like this `document.getElementById("yourname").value`.

```js
function validateName(){
    var nameVal = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
    var nameParts = nameVal.toString().split(" ");
    if (nameParts.length<2) {
        document.getElementById("yourname").nextSibling.innerHTML = "Please enter your First and Last Name.";} 
    else {
        document.getElementById("yourname").nextSibling.innerHTML = "Thank you for entering your First and Last Name!";
    }
}
```